# Laravel : Eloquent query doesn't find articles where publish_at datetime matches current datetime in cron command?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to make cron tasks on my laravel project for the very first time, I have to admit I'm a bit confused. I made a simple command to publish articles that were planned but there is something wrong with my eloquent query. I can't figure it out, can you help me find what I'm missing ?

Do I even have the right approach for this process ?

Articles have a status and a publish_at column, I'm trying to compare the publish_at date with current date every minute and if there is a match, change the status input to 'published' to publish one or multiple articles.

Kernel.php :

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('articles:publish')->everyMinute();
}
```

Commands/PublishArticles.php :

```
use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class PublishArticle extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'articles:publish';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // retrieve all planned articles that should be published now
        $articles = Article::where('status', 'planned')->where('publish_at', now())->get();

        foreach($articles as $article) {
            $article->status = 'published';
            $article->update();
        }

        return 0;
     }
}
```

I tried a few alternative for the query, like :

```
$articles = Article::where('status', 'planned')->where('publish_at', '>', now())->get();
$articles = Article::where('status', 'planned')->where('publish_at', '<', now())->get();
$articles = Article::where('status', 'planned')->where('publish_at', '>=', now())->get();
$articles = Article::where('status', 'planned')->where('publish_at', '<=', now())->get();
```

I also tried to use now() with ->toDateTimeString in case this was a date conversion problem.

EDIT :

Here are some more informations about the enviromnent.

The timezones of the app and the server are the same, as specified in config/app.php

When using the eloquent query in php tinker, here is what I get for previous articles :

```
input :
$articles = Article::where('status', 'planned')->where('publish_at', '<', now())->get();

output :
 all: [
   App\Models\Article {#4275
     id: 21,
     user_id: 1,
     title: "Article test 11",
     slug: "article-test-11",
     theme: "status",
     mainContent: "content",
     thumbnail: "IMG_20200926_234854.jpg",
     status: "planned",
     publish_at: "2021-04-14 20:10:00",
     created_at: "2021-04-14 19:02:54",
     updated_at: "2021-04-14 20:07:39",
   },
 ]
```

Comment: `php artisan schedule:work` needs to be running. You can set this up [as stated in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler) using cron jobs on your Linux OS. Remember, if you're deploying your application in containers (Docker, K8's) you'll need each stateless container to have the crontab.

Comment: yes it is already working, I can see it running when using the schedule:list command, and during the tries I made it sometimes updated the article as wished for previous or future articles, I never managed to make it work for the initial use (when we reach the planned time, publish it)

Comment: Why not load up `php tinker` and see what `Article::where()` returns for each one? Perhaps there's something else causing the issue like your DB timezone compared to your PHP timezone... You have not provided a full working environment for us to test with.

Comment: Sorry for the lacking environment. I managed to retrieve previous and future articles with tinker, but not the ones that are supposed to match (same datetime), I'm assuming I'm missing something...
The timezones are the same, this was an issue at the first tries, I managed to fix it by changing the timezone in the config/app.php, it's matching correctly now.

Comment: What output are you getting? Do you mind providing us with some sample output of which you get compared to your expected?

Comment: Edited my post with query output, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What is the exact issue? I am a bit confused to what it is that isn't working. Are the records you get from the Eloquent query not your expected data? Or are they not updating correctly? Sorry, its been a long day - to begin with I thought the question was about how to deploy Laravels Scheduler lol. You can use `echo` to directly output to the terminal inside the scheduler to see if its executing correctly FYI - sometimes exceptions are silent within the console for some peculiar reason.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was not clear enough, I should have mentioned eloquent instead of cron...
The exact issue is that I want my cron to process any article where its status is "planned" to be "published" when its date in the publish_at column matches current date. So the cron is checking every minute if the two dates match, and if so, update the article's status to publish it. I managed to make it work for past and future planned articles, but not for current datetime. When I reach current datetime (for ex. 2021-05-04 16:40), the query doesn't find the article planned at that datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on the issue, finally figured it out. The schedule:work command helped understand the problem, the cron wasn't in fact running enough though it was on the schedule:list command.

To make the query work there is a small delay between the cron running and the query working, so it wasn't matching any content between the dates.

```
$articles = Article::where('status', 'planned')->where('publish_at', '<', now())->get();

$articles = Article::where('status', 'planned')->where('publish_at', '<=', now())->get();
```

Those two queries finally work when the schedule:work is running. To make the process available on production, modify the crontab with following command :

```
crontab -e
```

And write this line in the file :

```
* * * * *  cd /path-to-laravel-app && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The cd /path-to-laravel-app (to replace with actual path for the app, can be found with "pwd" command) goes to the project file.

The * * * * * make the cron work all the time if I understood correctly, schedule:run makes the cron work.